# First attempt at writing a Function

Tags: function, excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple function for the sake of understanding, but I am not succeeding in getting the range right

Thanks

```
Function CountFind(ShtName as string, Rng As Range, FindWhat As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CountFind As Range
Dim lRow As Long

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
  lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Set CountFind= Range(Rng & lRow).Find(What:=FindWhat, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,     MatchCase:= _
                 False, SearchFormat:=False)

End Function
```

Then using it

```
Sub Test()
   If CountFind("mySheet", "K2:K", "Yes").Count > 0 Then MsgBox "Yes"
End Sub
```

Comment: There are several issues but wanted to mention that you are passing string into the function, not a proper range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument you use to call CountFind is not a range, it is a string. Therefore you must declare the second argument as a string.

The function returns something. You want it to return a range. So you need to declare the function as a range instead of declaring a range within the function.

The following works in my tests.

```
Function CountFind(ShtName As String, Rng As String, FindWhat As String) As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
' Dim CountFind As Range
Dim lRow As Long

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
  lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Set CountFind = Range(Rng & lRow).Find(What:=FindWhat, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                 False, SearchFormat:=False)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you teylyn, that was helpful to see